# Using regular expression to validate user input is an integer

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to validate a user's input.  I only want the user to be able to enter a positive or negative integer.  All other inputs (i.e. anything with letters) should be rejected

I have the code below at the minute, however I am getting an error. I'm assuming it has to do with the data types but am unsure how to fix this.

```
import re

number =input("Please enter a number: ")
number=int(number)
while not re.match("^[0-9 \-]+$", number):
    print ("Error! Make sure you only use numbers")
    number = input("Please enter a number: ")
print("You picked number "+ number)
```

Comment: You should not cast it to a number I believe. Do you get *TypeError: expected string or buffer*?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking along these lines.  I just assumed as it is number, I would need to use int?

Comment: Regular expressions only search for matches in *strings*.

Answer (score 6):

If all you care about is that the input was a valid numeric literal, don't even bother with the regexp.  `int` will correctly parse the string or raise an exception.

```
while True:
    s = input("Please enter a number: ")
    try:
        n = int(s)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Error! Make sure you only use numbers")
print("You picked number " + n)
```

Comment: That is what is called proactive thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions need strings as input, not numbers. Thus, you do not have to cast the string to number, and you can omit `number=int(number)`.

Here is a [working demo](https://ideone.com/gaCuMl):

```
number = "2"
if not re.match("^[0-9 -]+$", number):
    print ("Error! Make sure you only use numbers")
print("You picked number "+ number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

while  True:
    number =input("Please enter a number: ")
       # number=int(number) -- This raise an error, for regexp you need use "str"

    #while not re.match("^[0-9 \-]+$", number):
    # in [0-9 \-]  after 9 you use whitespace
    # Also in [0-9 \-]  if minus at the and, not need use backslash

if  re.match("-?\d+$", number) : # minus may be only in first position
    break

print ("Error! Make sure you only use numbers")
    # deleted     number = input("Please enter a number: ")

print("You picked number "+ number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = input(" ")#asks the user for an answer
ansnum = re.match("[0-9 \-]",answer)#checks to see if answer only contains numbers
while not ansnum: #whilst the answer does not contain numbers do....
   answer = input("Enter numbers as your answer: ")#asks the user for a valid answer
   ansnum = re.match("[0-9 \-]",answer)#checks to see if the answer contains numbers
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While code only answers are answers, please consider improving your post by adding context.